# Django ImportError: No module named 'webapp_credentials'

Tags: django, python-3.x, vagrant

I am running this code:

https://github.com/cndreisbach/call-for-service/blob/master/docs/src/development.md

When im running this part of code in my Vagrant shell :

```
python3 ./cfs/manage.py migrate --settings=cfs.settings.local
```

It's returning me that there is no `"ImportError: No module named 'webapp_credentials'"`

This is the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cfs/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 351, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 697, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/vagrant/cfs/cfs/settings/local.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import *
  File "/vagrant/cfs/cfs/settings/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    from webapp_credentials import creds
ImportError: No module named 'webapp_credentials'
```

Is webapp_credentials a module of python OS how do i fix this?

Comment: What is `webapp_credentials`?

Comment: https://github.com/cndreisbach/call-for-service/blob/master/cfs/cfs/settings/base.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webapp_credentials.py is on .gitignore, that is why migrate can't find it.

You need this file, which is not versioned in this git repository of your link.

Comment: I don't get it, which file i need then? How I fix this?

Comment: Is this repository yours? If not you need to get this file from the owner to make it work as the migration references it.